# KeyPress Results in Double Event

Tags: vb.net, events, textbox

Pretty simple: I have a textbox which should write to an Excel cell when the user hits the Return key. The problem is the write to the cell is happening twice, so I get two of the entry the user makes. I have checked that I only have the KeyPress active in the TextBox and not the Form as well, and have also tried the KeyDown/KeyUp events as well with the same result. I've tried two different keyboards, and slowed the keyboard poll rate down with the same result. I also added a global output to a message box to track how many times the routine gets called, and strangely it says "1" every time.

I am stumped.

```
Private Sub vbKeyReturnNC(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim NewController As String
    NewController = TextBox1.Text

    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(13) Then
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        oExcel = New Excel.Application      'Create a new instance of Excel
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\QA Controller Test Files\New Controller Template.xlsm", "C:\QA Controller Test Files\" & NewController & ".xlsm")
        oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\QA Controller Test Files\" & NewController & ".xlsm")
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
        oSheet.Range("B1").Value = TextBox1.Text
        oExcel.Visible = True               'Show it to the user
        Count = Count + 1                   'Count how many times this event triggers
        MsgBox(Count)                       'Output number of times run

        oBook = Nothing                     'Disconnect from Excel (let the user take over)
        oExcel = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is running twice it would try to create a file with the same name twice and should error on the `CopyFile` line on the second pass. As you simply can't have two files with the same name either you are getting an error or the routine is not running twice. Take a close look at the file names that are created to see what value of TextBox1 was used. That may help find the issue.

Comment: What about `TextChanged` event? Try to catch which event is triggered, it may need an additional code I guess. Worst case scenario, just discard the textbox and add a new textbox and check what happens with the events.

Comment: Also, try changing `e.KeyChar = ChrW(13)` to `e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you haven't added a second event handler someplace?  The `Handles` clause on the sub automatically adds a handler.  If you added a handler manually in code, with `AddHandler` you will have a 2nd one attached.  This will make it look like the event is firing twice.

Answer (score 0):

My code was

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    evKeyPressed(sender, e)
End Sub
Private Sub evKeyPressed(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
```

The second sub with "Handles ..." seemed firing twice.

Thank you Brad!